# How can I paginate my table with max of 5 rows on the same view in Grails?

Tags: grails

This is my gsp view where I have to show the pagination but I am not getting any pagination and below that I've printed the job count and I am getting the correct job count.

```
<div class="paginate">
    <g:paginate total="${total}" maxsteps="1" next="Forward" prev="Back" controller="job" action="viewJobs"/>
    </div>
    Job Count======${total} //Just for check
```

My controller code :

```
def viewJobs() {
    User userEmail = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
    List<Job> list1 = Job.findAllByCompany(userEmail.company,[max:5])
    println "******list1*******" + list1
    render(view: 'viewJob', model: [jobs: list1,total:list1.size()])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action should look like

```
def viewJobs(Integer offset) {
    User userEmail = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
    List<Job> list1 = Job.findAllByCompany(userEmail.company,[max:5,offset:offset])
    println "******list1*******" + list1
    render(view: 'viewJob', model: [jobs: list1,total:Job.countByCompany(userEmail.company)])
}
```

Pagination works with offset parameter (just like in SQL) and totalCount should be total number of records in DB not the size of the list(which will be always less than or equal to 5 in your case)